# What are other benefits of using release mode in continuous integration practice?

Tags: git, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, release-management, git-flow

A single release branch into which shipped code is merged and tagged by release version.

The stable code is merged, from the master, into the release branch when preparing for a release.

The CI server builds in **release mode** and optimizes for performance.

What are other benefits there for the release branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a release branch is good to have since it is always clear exactly what has been shipped. This can be useful if you want to analyze a bug in production, e.g. to try out bugfixes in the right environment. In that case you can just check out the release branch.

As a side note, I can mention that I wouldn't personally use the scheme described, I would recommend [GitHub flow](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/) or possibly [git flow](https://datasift.github.io/gitflow/IntroducingGitFlow.html).

Comment: Checked https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/ What is the cycle time for the branches. Does the branch live more than a day? What happens in an environment where continuous deployment practice wants to be implemented.

Comment: @RıfatErdemSahin You should ideally have short branch lives, one or at most a couple of days. You should set up your continuous integration to build branches too, ideally they should be deployed in staging environments too.